# Error connecting Beanstalk application with external rds instance: AWS and Spring Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application on AWS using **Elastic Beanstalk, RDS (MySQL) and CodePipeline with GitHub and CodeBuild**. My setup-

1. Created a Beanstalk environment. (not in a vpc) (with different security group created automatically)
2. Created a RDS instance. (in the default vpc) (in a different security group then ebs and inbound rules set to accept from public internet with 0.0.0.0/0)
3. Created a code pipeline with CodeBuild and GitHub. Added the db credentials as environment properties in pipeline and referenced in the **application.properties-**

```
spring.datasource.username=${db-username}
spring.datasource.password=${db-password}
```

**My problem-**

1. When I hit the url generated by beanstalk, I get **502 Bad Gateway error.**
2. When I try to hit one of the api endpoints, I do not get a response and get following log message-

```
Jun 17 20:28:26 ip-172-31-20-71 web: 2023-06-17T20:28:26.292Z  WARN 3516 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1045, SQLState: 28000
Jun 17 20:28:26 ip-172-31-20-71 web: 2023-06-17T20:28:26.292Z ERROR 3516 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Access denied for user '${db-username}'@'172.31.20.71' (using password: YES)
Jun 17 20:28:26 ip-172-31-20-71 web: 2023-06-17T20:28:26.303Z ERROR 3516 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [Access denied for user '${db-username}'@'172.31.20.71' (using password: YES)] [n/a]
```